# Stack Scanning on ARM vs x86-64

Tags: performance, x86, garbage-collection, arm, x86-64

I was told recently that performing [stack scanning](https://www.usenix.org/legacy/events/jvm01/full_papers/barabash/barabash.pdf) on modern ARM processors was slower than performing the same scan on modern x86-64 processors. I was wondering if this is true, and if so, why so.

I know that modern x86-64 processors have a [stack engine](http://www.agner.org/optimize/microarchitecture.pdf), however, it seems to me that this would only come into play when issuing pushes, pops, calls, and rets. As stack scanning simply reads memory, it would seem that this Stack Engine wouldn't have any benefit here.

Does anyone have any insight into this claim?

Comment: Yes - garbage collection is the context within which I am investigating stack scanning. I agree with you about the stack engine being irrelevant - I was just listing it to show what I ::do:: know.

Comment: You don't use `pop` to scan stack memory; it has to be non-destructive, but popping would leave your data below RSP (the stack pointer).  So yes, it's irrelevant.  Possibly on a 64-bit machine, it's easier to quickly distinguish valid pointers from non-pointers?  (As opposed to on 32-bit ARM).  Or x86-64 CPUs have larger caches and more cache / memory bandwidth than typical ARM CPUs did in 2014 or whenever it was that your source heard this fact.